# liferay 7 insert model to database from MVCPorlet

Tags: model, liferay, addition

I trying insert a new model in MVCPortlet with Util class from service builder.

I have EmployeeLocalServiceUtil generate from service. I able success insert new model to database but i found the incremental id is always 0. I saw some post intro EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.increment() method but i found this method is not exist from my generate ServiceUtil class.

I follow some post add id-type="increment" in entity in service.xml and after buildService I found the increment() method still not exist.

Any idea?

EmployeePortlet.java

```
package com.webster.employee.portlet;

import com.webster.employee.constants.EmployeeConstant;
import com.webster.employee.constants.EmployeePortletKeys;
import com.webster.model.Employee;
import com.webster.model.ThemeBuilder;
import com.webster.service.EmployeeLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.PortletDisplay;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.theme.ThemeDisplay;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.WebKeys;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.Portlet;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

/**
 * @author admin
 */
@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.display-name=employee Portlet",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
        "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
        "javax.portlet.name=" + EmployeePortletKeys.Employee,
        "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
    },
    service = Portlet.class
)
public class EmployeePortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
            throws IOException, PortletException {

        try {

            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay= (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
            PortletDisplay portletDisplay= themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay();
            String portletId= portletDisplay.getId();

            Employee employee = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.findEmployeeByPortletId(portletId);

            if(employee==null){
                employee = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.createEmployee(0);
                employee.setPortlet_id(portletId);
                employee.setSettings("");               
                employee = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.addEmployee(employee);
                _log.info("DEV TEST employee is created = "+employee.getId());
            }else{
                _log.info("employee was exist = "+employee.getId());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            _log.error(e.toString());
        }

        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }

    private Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(EmployeePortlet.class);

}
```

Service.xml

```
<entity name="Employee" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="employee">
        <column name="id" type="int" primary="true" id-type="increment"></column>
        <column name="portlet_id" type="String"></column>
        <column name="settings" type="String"></column>
    </entity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .increment() method not necessary. I remove increment() and use following code,

```
employee = EmployeeLocalServiceUtil.createEmployee(0);
```

and configure id-type=increment and run buildservice.

```
<column name="id" type="int" primary="true" id-type="increment"></column>
```

I found inserted Employee record id is increase 1 for each transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CounterLocalServiceUtil with your Employee.class? Probably  will fix your problem.